# While loop joins all rows to one?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to fetch all rows from a table with a foreign key. My while loop returns only one row with scattered data from the two rows that is supposed to return.

```
$ins = 'SELECT * FROM car_reg INNER JOIN User_Details ON car_reg.User_ID = User_Details.User_ID WHERE car_regColumn = userinput AND car_regColumn = userinput';
$qur = $con->query($ins);
if(mysqli_num_rows($qur) > 0){
while{$g = mysqli_fetch_array($qur)
$response = array("status" => 1 "Surname" => $g['fname'], $"Surname" => $g["fname"], "LastName" => $g["lname"],  "CarType" => $g["Car_Type"], "NumberPlate" => $g["Number_plate"], "CarImage" => $g["car_image"], "Gender" => $g["Gender"], "Mobile" => $g["Telephone"], "Price" => $g["Price"], "PickupTime" => $g["arrival_time"]);}}
```

`json_encode($response);`

Comment: You are overwriting $response. Use $response[]

Answer (score 1):

Your `$reponse` has been overwritten in `while` loop. Declare an array and push fetched data into it. Try this code:

```
$response = array();
$ins = 'SELECT * FROM car_reg INNER JOIN User_Details ON car_reg.User_ID = User_Details.User_ID WHERE car_regColumn = userinput AND car_regColumn = userinput';
$qur = $con->query($ins);
if(mysqli_num_rows($qur) > 0){
while($g = mysqli_fetch_array($qur))
{
$response[] = array("status" => 1, "Surname" => $g['fname'], "Surname" => $g["fname"], "LastName" => $g["lname"],  "CarType" => $g["Car_Type"], "NumberPlate" => $g["Number_plate"], "CarImage" => $g["car_image"], "Gender" => $g["Gender"], "Mobile" => $g["Telephone"], "Price" => $g["Price"], "PickupTime" => $g["arrival_time"]);
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `,` after `"status" => 1` , also `$"Surname"` this is correct you think ?

Comment: @alex Thanks for pointing out miner issues. code is updated now.

Comment: why negative vote? Major issue was with `$response` variable, i just convert it into array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you overwrite your response array each time you loop.

So you should fix this to:

```
     $response[] = array("status" => 1 "Surname" => $g['fname'], "LastName" => $g["lname"],  "CarType" => $g["Car_Type"], "NumberPlate" => $g["Number_plate"], "CarImage" => $g["car_image"], "Gender" => $g["Gender"], "Mobile" => $g["Telephone"], "Price" => $g["Price"], "PickupTime" => $g["arrival_time"]);
```

**EDIT**

And yes, of course the key $"Surname" is not correct.You should change that too